# .NET C# - WinForm border

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a WinForm without a border (borderless). How can I add a 1px black border to the form?

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width - 5, Height - 5, 10, 10)); // adjust these parameters to get the lookyou want.
    }


    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
    (
         int nLeftRect, // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
         int nTopRect, // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
         int nRightRect, // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
         int nBottomRect, // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
         int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
         int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
     );
```

I need a borderless form but I want to add a 1px border.

Comment: can we see some code?? preferably designer.cs

Answer (score 7):

In the `Paint` event handler of the form, add this code:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1));
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: this will draw rectangle inside form, not as border

Comment: Yup, but override OnPaint() instead.

Comment: @Stecya - how can you tell the difference?

Comment: Enable Header, and you will see

Comment: @Stecya: Where is the problem?, Add `1 px` Padding to the form. It'll be OK.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a fully docked `Panel`, and another fully docked `Panel` as a child control. Set the padding of the outer `Panel` to 1 and the background color of the outer `Panel` to black.

Then set the background color of the inner `Panel` to `SystemColors.Control`.

Comment: @MehdiLAMRANI Simple? Using 2 instances of a control that has **nothing** to do with borders I wouldn't call it simple at all. Stupid? Very much. At least with the `OnPaint` override you can clearly see what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to paint,

Add 4 panels width or height 2 or 4 and black background colour
after dock them in 4 sides differently on top, right, bottom, left respectively

```
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

        Panel pnlTop = new Panel() { Height = 4, Dock = DockStyle.Top, BackColor = Color.Green };
        this.Controls.Add(pnlTop);

        Panel pnlRight = new Panel() { Width = 4, Dock = DockStyle.Right, BackColor = Color.Green };
        this.Controls.Add(pnlRight);

        Panel pnlBottom = new Panel() { Height = 4, Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, BackColor = Color.Green };
        this.Controls.Add(pnlBottom);

        Panel pnlLeft = new Panel() { Width = 4, Dock = DockStyle.Left, BackColor = Color.Green };
        this.Controls.Add(pnlLeft);
```

You can also change their mouse pointer to resize icons also you can resize the form writing some code on mouse events.